# How to create a custom email with a domain that is used in the netlify react application?

Tags: node.js, email, dns, nodemailer, netlify

I have a react application that runs in Netlify using a custom domain name. I want to create an email with this domain and send notifications from my server via Node.js and Nodemailer.
I was thinking of doing this with Postfix. 
How to use my domain in both Netlify and Postfix?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Netlify account -> Domains tab -> Select the domain -> Add the required DNS records for your Postfix setup.